# Implementing fisheye for force directed graph on Rails 4 (using d3.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am trying to implement fisheye distortion on a force directed graph using d3.js.  For some reason, the distortion works on the links but not the nodes.  This might be caused by the nodes being g elements, but I am not sure.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
var svg, node, link;

function make_graph() {

  // Clear out the div first
  $("#display_graph svg:first").remove();

  // Sets size
  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  // Maps groups to colors
  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  // Select the div and append a svg
  svg = d3.select("#display_graph").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Pull json from graph
  var json_from_db = $('.graph_json').data('json');
  var json_nodes = json_from_db.nodes
  var json_links = json_from_db.links

  // Sets up the force directed graph
  var charge_val = $('#charge').val();
  var link_distance_val = $('#link_distance').val();
  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(charge_val)
      .linkDistance(link_distance_val)
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(json_nodes)
      .links(json_links)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json_links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var font_size_px = $('#font_size').val();
  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json_nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("font-size", font_size_px)
      .call(force.drag);

  var radius = $('#radius').val();
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });

  $('#fisheye_btn').click( function() {
    var glyph_color = $(this).css('color');
    // original color is white
    orig_color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

    if (glyph_color == orig_color) {
      $(this).css('color', 'orange');
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', orig_color);
    };
  });

};

function make_fisheye() {
  var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
    .radius(200)
    .distortion(2);

  svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    node.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 4.5; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });
  });
}
```

Eventually, I want the user to be able to turn the distortion on or off by clicking a button.  Thanks for your help!

I updated the code.  I can turn the distortion on or off with a button click now.

```
// Make force directed graph on button click
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#refresh_btn").click( function() {
    make_graph();
  });
});

// Turn on and off fisheye distortion
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#fisheye_btn').click( function() {
    var glyph_color = $(this).css('color');
    // original color is white
    orig_color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

    if (glyph_color == orig_color) {
      $(this).css('color', 'orange');
      make_graph();
      make_fisheye();
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', orig_color);
      make_graph();
    };
  });
});

var svg, node, link;

function make_graph() {

  // Clear out the div first
  $("#display_graph svg:first").remove();

  // Sets size
  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  // Maps groups to colors
  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  // Select the div and append a svg
  svg = d3.select("#display_graph").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Pull json from graph
  var json_from_db = $('.graph_json').data('json');
  var json_nodes = json_from_db.nodes
  var json_links = json_from_db.links

  // Sets up the force directed graph
  var charge_val = $('#charge').val();
  var link_distance_val = $('#link_distance').val();
  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(charge_val)
      .linkDistance(link_distance_val)
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(json_nodes)
      .links(json_links)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json_links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var font_size_px = $('#font_size').val();
  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json_nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("font-size", font_size_px)
      .call(force.drag);

  var radius = $('#radius').val();
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });
};

function make_fisheye() {
  var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
    .radius(200)
    .distortion(2);

  svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    node.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 4.5; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, I am still having issues with just the links being distorted.  The nodes are actually g elements, which I am becoming more and more convinced might be the problem.  Is there a way to select elements inside the g element using d3.js?  I am surprised that the fisheye distortion is not just passed on to the elements inside the g element.  Maybe my guess is wrong?

**New Code**

Now both the nodes and links are distorted on a button click!  Here is the code:

```
// Global variables
var svg, node, link; 
var fisheye_on = false;

// Make force directed graph on button click
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#refresh_btn").click( function() {
    // Make sure fisheye is turned off
    $('#fisheye_btn').css('color', 'white');
    fisheye_on = false;
    make_graph();
  });
});

// Turn on and off fisheye distortion
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#fisheye_btn').click( function() {
    var glyph_color = $(this).css('color');
    // original color is white
    orig_color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

    if (glyph_color == orig_color) {
      $(this).css('color', 'orange');
      fisheye_on = true;
      make_graph();
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', orig_color);
      fisheye_on = false;
      make_graph();
    };
  });
});


function make_graph() {

  // Clear out the div first
  $("#display_graph svg:first").remove();

  // Sets size
  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  // Maps groups to colors
  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  // Select the div and append a svg
  svg = d3.select("#display_graph").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Pull json from graph
  var json_from_db = $('.graph_json').data('json');
  var json_nodes = json_from_db.nodes
  var json_links = json_from_db.links

  // Sets up the force directed graph
  var charge_val = $('#charge').val();
  var link_distance_val = $('#link_distance').val();
  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(charge_val)
      .linkDistance(link_distance_val)
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(json_nodes)
      .links(json_links)
      .start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json_links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var font_size_px = $('#font_size').val();
  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json_nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("font-size", font_size_px)
      .call(force.drag);

  var radius = $('#radius').val();
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  if (fisheye_on == false) {

    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    });

  } else {

    var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
      .radius(200)
      .distortion(2);

    svg.on("mousemove", function() {
      fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

      node.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); });

      node.selectAll("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; })
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 4.5; });

      node.selectAll("text")
          .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
          .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; });

      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });
    });
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, I have come across another issue.  There seems to be an initial lag when the distortion is applied.  The nodes get distorted first and then the links get distorted.  Not sure what is causing this.  Any hints?

**Public JSFiddle**

I managed to replicated the issue in a public JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cspears2002/vVL99/

In order to make the graph, just click "Make Graph".  Clicking "Fisheye" will turn the fisheye distortion on and off.  The issue is that the nodes are distorted first and then the links follow.  I want nodes and links to be distorted at the same time.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: In your `make_fisheye` function, try `node.selectAll("circle").each...`.

Comment: That worked.  Came across another issue though.  Will post the code soon.

Comment: It would help if you could put a complete working example on jsfiddle or something like that.